# Why compound expressions?

Tags: julia

This is an example from a book I am reading:

```
volume = begin
    len = 10
    breadth = 20
    height = 30
    len * breadth * height
end
```

Why do I need compound expressions?? I could just write `volume = 10 * 20 * 30` or `volume = len * breadth * height` or write a function for that or an anonymous function...

Why do I use `begin` and `end`? Or the probably better question: **When**  do I use them, as I guess the example above from the book is probably not very good.

Comment: What book is that? as you also not the example isn't particularly good

Comment: "Learning Julia", as available here: https://epdf.pub/learning-julia.html (page 127)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess there are many situations in which [`begin ... end` blocks](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#begin) are handy, but as you noted you can often also achieve a similar effect with other constructs, such as functions, etc.

What could `begin ... end` blocks be used for?

- To simply "contain" variables and their names: `len`, `breadth`, and `height` will only exist within the block and not pollute the surrounding namespace.
- To apply macros to a block of code rather then individual statements. For example `@inbounds begin <all my code without bounds checking goes here> end` or wrapping a `@time begin ... end` around a piece of code.
- To create a local scope in a surrounding global scope (to avoid [global scope confusions](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/repl-and-for-loops-scope-behavior-change/13514) for example). (Note that as has been pointed out in the comments `begin ... end` does **not** introduce a local scope, but the argument holds for the similar `let ... end` block.)

In particular the second point is what I use them for in my codes.

Comment: I also had to reassure myself, but `begin` blocks [do _not_ introduce scope](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/). On the other hand, they convert a sequence of statements into an expression, which can be handy if you generate code with/from a macro.

Comment: Oh, thanks, in that regard I confused it with `let ... end` which does introduce a local scope. Will correct my answer.

Comment: I make the same wrong assumption all the time :) It's just what one would expect.

Comment: @crstnbr Your first bullet is still misleading. It still seems to say that `begin` blocks introduce a local scope.

Answer (score 7):

To generalize what everyone else has said: blocks allow you to convert a list of *statements* (syntactic "phrases" that have no values, i.e., can't be assigned) to one *expression* (a "phrase" that represents values and *can* be assigned).

For example, while you shouldn't, you can write

```
x = begin
    s = 0
    for i = 1:10
        s += i^2
    end
    s
end
```

to assign `x` to the result of a looping operation.  (With the restriction that the last statement in the sequence must actually be an expression -- otherwise, you would have no value for the expression.)

A legitimate use case of this is generated code.  For example, you might turn

```
x = @somthing bla blub
```

into

```
x = begin
   (stuff involving bla and blub)
end
```

transparently to the user, while the `@something` can freely generate any language constructs.

Or if you want to write an anonymous function with a longer body (and not use the `function` form):

```
f = x -> begin
   ...
end
```

Comment: A slight clarification: In Julia, statements do have values and *can* be assigned. So you can do `x = y = 1`, `a = if false end`, and `b = for i in 1:2 end`, after which `x` has the value `1`, and `a` and `b` both have the value `nothing`.

Comment: Oh, here's a more useful example of assigning the value of an `if-else` statement: `a = if false; 1 else 2 end`. In this case, `a` equals `2`.

Comment: Right, they have values and are techincally expressions, too. Assignment is an expression, since it's basically `setproperty!`/`setindex!`, and it's "traditionally" a thing for it to have a value (in C-like languages). Same for `if-else`, which is an expression in a couple of languages. But `for` and `if` without `else` having a "default" value of `nothing`, I see that as merely an artifact.

Answer (score 6):

One use for these blocks is in comprehensions:

```
A = [ begin
           x = y^2
           x - x^2 + 2
         end
         for y = 1:5 ]
```

You could make a function and use it inside the comprehension instead, but sometimes this is convenient. It’s used whenever you want to use a multiline block of code somewhere, eg to pass as an argument to a macro (which is very commonly used for `@testset` from the Test standard library).

Comment: Not to oppose your point but one could just write `y^2 - y^4 + 2` in this case. Perhaps it would be better to show an example where two (or more) steps are really needed.

Comment: @crstnbr you are right, but I just initially used the example from the book and was simply interested what a sensible usage would be.

Comment: Like, to save calculating some expensive intermediate value twice.

Answer (score 5):

Simply put: “begin” just denotes a code block (see the docs on this: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#begin).

In the example above, it’s not clear that there is any value to using a begin block vs declaring a function.

I don’t see that keyword being used very much in code and I personally have never used it in practice. My suggestion so to just use a function as it will do the same thing.

Comment: I haven't used Julia, yet, but this is exactly what I am thinking. However, when the language was designed (presumably very smart) people must have had an idea in mind, right?

Comment: I agree with @logankilpatrick that in many cases you'd want to use functions instead. But I think there are reasons for the existence of these blocks (see my answer).

Comment: @Georgery Turning a sequence of statements into an expression is a useful thing sometimes (cf. `progn` in LISP).

Comment: as you correctly note, it seems nonsensical in the context